# mysql lib_msqludf_json error: Can't initialize function 'json_object'; Invalid json member name - name cannot be empty

Tags: mysql

I installed lib_mysqludf_json correctly. Functions like json_array, json_members are working correctly. There is a thing with the json_object function.

I have a table with two columns key and value. I run this query

`select json_object(key, value) as settings from ph_settings where key = 1`

I get this error

`ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'json_object'; Invalid json member name - name cannot be empty`

What is this about? Now from error message it is somewhat implied that json_member should be wrapped within json-object function. But in the documentation there was this example, and according to them it works.

```
select json_object(
    customer_id
   ,first_name
   ,last_name
   ,last_update
) as customer
from   customer 
where  customer_id =1;
```

Please help...

Comment: What's in your DB table for `key=1`?

Comment: only one row is there right now, just a test table. value is abc

Comment: I have exactly the same problem on an ubuntu 12.04 distro running mysql 5.6 ... select json_object(Customer_id,Name,DB_Prefix,CUSTOMER,SITE,COMPANY_LOGO) as C from customers;
ERROR 1123 (HY000): Can't initialize function 'json_object'; Invalid json member name - name cannot be empty

Answer (score 1):

I found it worked only if you named every column as follows:

```
select 
    json_object(id as 'id', name as 'name',  address as 'address') AS 'blobby' 
from 
    tempo_1;
```

In the above example the column aliases don't need the '' delimiters and also the final row alias seems to be optional so the following also appears to be valid

```
select 
    json_object(id as id, name as name,  address as address) 
from 
    tempo_1;
```